# Converting From 4-bit RAW Audio to WAV (or another output format)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

Okay, so I've got some .raw files from an old game (Zork Nemesis) and determined that they're audio files, however I'm having trouble converting them into something meaningful.

With a bit of trial and error in Audacity I've found that I can listen to a still noisy version of the audio using raw file input settings of 8-bit signed PCM in stereo with a sample rate of 22050hz. However, my suspicion is that the files may in fact be encoded in 4-bits with a sample rate of 44100hz, but I'm having trouble finding a tool that can handle this.

What I'm looking for is either a tool that can handle 4-bit raw formats, or even a tool that can determine (or guess at) the format of a given .raw file, so I know for sure what I'm dealing with (as I'm just going by trial and error so far).

I've tried `sox`, but I'm most likely doing something wrong as it complains of an unsupported size:

```
sox -r 44100 -e signed -b 4 -c 2 in.raw out.wav
```

I was also going to try `ffmpeg`, but I can't find the appropriate format/codec to set.

In case it gives any further clues; I've tried various combinations of settings, increasing sample size while decreasing sample rate increases the (white-)noise, and even 8-bit is still noisy, which is why I'm thinking 4-bit. I've tried signed and unsigned, which strangely doesn't seem to make much of a difference

Comment: can you post online your sample 4 bit audio file ? maybe at box.com or such so we can give it a try

Answer (score 0):

sox expects .raw input with 8-bit or higher encoding. So if you run

```
sox -r 44100 -e signed -b 8 -c 2 in.raw out.wav
```

it should work just fine. So either the file is actually 8(+)-bit encoded or you need find a converter which accepts this form of input.